# Storing crontab file inside my project

Tags: cron

Currently, I am editing my production server's crons by typing `crontab -e`.
I would like to store my crontab definitions inside my project, and have my system to load them from there.

Is there any way I can set up the servers existing crontabs to point to an include like this?

`IncludeOtherCrontab /path/to/my/project/project.crontab`

My system is CentOS release 5.4 (Final)

Comment: Not a portable way. Note that you still have to notify `crond` after you update the configuration, you typically can't just update files behind `crond`'s back. Will prolly need something like: update my-cron then `crontab -l | awk '{ strip old subsection and replace with new } | crontab`

Comment: It's easier to just use /etc/cron.d/ and then you don't have to worry about notifying cron that the file has changed.

Comment: Not on Solaris you don't... (i.e. not portably) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this portably (i.e. not using `/etc/cron.d`), assuming your deployment script must coexist with third-party crontab entries *and* provided your deployment script can execute commands on the target node, not just upload files:

`test -f project.crontab && { { crontab -u user -l | awk '/^#BEGIN PROJECT SECTION/{hide=1;next}/^#END PROJECT SECTION/{hide=0;next}!hide{print}' ; echo '#BEGIN PROJECT SECTION' ; cat project.crontab ; echo '#END PROJECT SECTION' ; } | crontab -u user - ; }`

The above verifies that your project-specific crontab section exists, filters it from the given user's crontab (if it already is there, does nothing otherwise), appends the project section, then reloads the lot.

`crontab -u user -` adds all the project-specific crontab entries into `user`'s crontab file.

Answer (score 2):

---

I don't know whether you can include other files in your base crontab file, but maybe you could just order in your crontab to reload/alter it's contents?

Say, every 5 minutes cron executes your bash script which reads your 'project.crontab' and appends it to your crontab file.

Comment: This is a good idea. The most elegant solution would be one like Byron Whitlock's, but if none of those work then this is a terrific backup idea. It lets me store the cron specification in my project where I want it.

Comment: Actually, instead of the cron updating every 5 minutes, it could just be part of my deploy script to update the cron.

Comment: Yes, that would work too. Actually it depends on when does your 'project.crontab' change and when do you want to reload it. If it only changes when you rebuild/deploy your project then it is probably the best to update crontab immediately.

Comment: See below on how to do that without kicking `crond` in the groin every 5 minutes (assuming your deployment script can issue commands on the target node, not just upload files.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to put your crontab entry into a file under `/etc/cron.d/`. Take a look at some existing files there to see the syntax. You can either copy your file there manually (or via an installer such as rpm) or just use a symlink to the file located in your installed directory.